# BooleanToVisibilityConverter works on Textblock and not on UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a windows phone project.
There is something i don't really understand about my xaml.

Here it is:

```
<Page
x:Class="CitiBox.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:converters="using:CitiBox.Converters"
xmlns:views="using:CitiBox.Views"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Test1" Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test2" Visibility="{Binding Test1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>-->
    <views:LoadingView Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <views:DrawerView Visibility="{Binding Test1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>    
</Page>
```

As you can see there are two textblock that are commented and two views (user controls). You also can see that i binded the visibility of those four elements to two booleans with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

What surprises me is that if i test this code with the two textblocks, it works and if i try it with the views it doesn't. my views contains only a textblock with a message, nothing fancy..

Here is what they look like:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="CitiBox.Views.LoadingView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CitiBox.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400"
DataContext="{Binding Loading, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Loading!!"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Would you have an idea of what it could be ?
Thanks in advance,
Guillaume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of DataContext. Your `MainPage` has a DataContext :

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

LoadingView also has a DataContext

So, when you write this code :

You try to find `Test2` as a field in the DataContext of the LoadingView because you're in the same View. To avoid this behavior, you can try this :

```
<views:LoadingView Visibility="{Binding  ElementName=Page,Path=DataContext.Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Or you can write a class called `NavigationService` inherited from `INavigationService` (MVVM Light)
Each view in your project will be a Page and you will be a transition (like fade) between all your pages

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserControl`, you are explicitly setting the `DataContext`.

```
DataContext="{Binding Loading, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

This means that the following binding will not work:

```
Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

The reason why is because the binding is looking for `Test2` in the **current DataContext of the UserControl**. Instead, you need to be looking for `Test2` in the **parent control's DataContext**.

Try this instead:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Test2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Comment: I get an error saying that "The member "AncestorType" is not recognized or is not accessible." and also the error that says "Cannot resolve DataContext ... ..." any clue ?

Answer (score -1):

I think your Problem is `DataContext` Because The Page DataContext is

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Where as You set usercontrol dataContext as `DataContext="{Binding Loading, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` Try to Change Your Code Like this

```
<Page x:Class="CitiBox.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:converters="using:CitiBox.Converters"
      xmlns:views="using:CitiBox.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
      x:Name="Page">

<Page.Resources>
   <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Test1" Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test2" Visibility="{Binding Test1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>-->
    <views:LoadingView Visibility="{Binding  ElementName=Page,Path=DataContext.Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <views:DrawerView Visibility="{Binding  ElementName=Page,Path=DataContext.Test1, Converter={StaticResourceBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>    
</Page>
```

Comment: If i do this, the DataContext of my Page won't be MainViewModel anymore but LoadingViewModel which i don't want at all.